# How does a slot with parameter connect to a signal?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

These are member function of the class downloading files via `HTTP` with `QNetworkAccessManager`:

```
Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Downloader::onResult);
}

// ...

void Downloader::onResult(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error()){
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    } else {
        QFile *file = new QFile("C:/example/file.xml");
        if(file->open(QFile::WriteOnly)){
            file->write(reply->readAll()); 
            file->close();
        emit onReady();
        }
    }
}
```

How can `onResult` use `reply` if this parameter isn't passed in `connect` in the constructor? Where does `onResult` get it? This isn't a mistake, the class works properly.

UPD: I've [found out](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) that the signal `QNetworkAccessManager::finished` has a parameter `QNetworkReply *reply`. I guess it has to do with this situation, but I don't know how it does yet.

Comment: Could you show where to make the download request?

Comment: This behaviour is the reason why they invented signal/slots. A signal can pass a value to a slot. Read the documentation.

Comment: Offcourse it does: `QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)` which has same argument as of `Downloader::onResult(QNetworkReply *reply)`

Comment: @AlexF, sorry I didn't get your point?